# Memory Issue While reading zip file from S3 using Python(boto3 package)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Please find the code snippet

```
s3_resource =  boto3.resource('s3',       
   aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXX',       
   aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXX')

file = s3_resource.Object('xxxxxx',filePath).get()
with io.BytesIO(file['Body'].read()) as t:
        t.seek(0)
        with ZipFile(t, 'r') as myzip:
```

The file is a compressed zip file.
I am getting memory error at (with io.BytesIO(file['Body'].read()) as t:)
Is there an efficient was of reading the compressed zip file from S3 using boto3 package in python

Comment: You didn't say what you're trying to do with the zip file. Maybe you could just download it to a temp file and then read it from disk?

Comment: iam searching for a specific file in the zip file and then trying to read the contents in that file

Comment: Further there are lot of files to be processed, so is it appropriate to download and read the content in it?

Comment: Writing it to a temp file is probably the way to go. Then you can use [`myzip.open(name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) to read just the file or files you're interested in.

Comment: Well, you're downloading the zip file either way. It's just a question of whether you're downloading directly into memory or onto disk. If you use temp files appropriately, they'll clean up after themselves.

Comment: Can you point to some example code